# need assistance with awk using system in Solaris

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, solaris

Trying to get more familiar with awk, and am using system command to scp a bunch of files across servers.

So I tried this, but it doesn't work. Does not error, just doesn't do anything.

`ls *.dmp | awk ' {system("nohup scp "$1" username@server:/server/file/path/ &")}'`

However, this works

`ls *.dmp | awk ' {print "nohup scp "$1" username@server:/server/file/path/ &"}' > scp.sh && chmod +x scp.sh && ./scp.sh`

Goal is just trying to execute everything that awk returns.

Comment: Awk is not the right tool for the job here. You should really just use a shell `for` loop.

Comment: First thing I think of when I hear "awk ... Solaris" is: which awk are you using? Ensure it's /usr/xpg4/bin/awk.

Comment: Simply `nohup scp *.dmp user@server:/path/ &` would suffice.

Comment: How about `scp *.dmp username@server:/server/file/path/`?

Comment: Solaris 10's `/usr/bin/awk` will not raise an error when you make a call to an undefined function (such as `system`);  the return value of the function will be whatever its argument is. Instead, use either `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `nawk`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It is solaris 10. Thank you, nawk worked!

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Can you post that as an awesome. So I can close this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solaris 10's `/usr/bin/awk` doesn't have a `system` function, and it will not raise an error when you make a call to an undefined function; the return value of the function will be whatever its argument is. Instead, use either `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `nawk`.

As Glenn and Andrew pointed out, if all you need to do is run a shell command multiple times with one argument varying each time, this can be done in the shell itself without getting awk involved.

```
for f in *.dmp
do
    nohup scp "$f" username@server:/server/file/path/ &
done
```